# adding multiple multibuttons to a form after querying a webservice

Tags: codenameone

I tried adding multiple nultibuttons to a form in my app(an event management app), I first connected to a webservice I created using the web service wizard, the return type being a String[] which I intend to use on d multibuttons on d screen.
Everything seemed fine buy when I run the program it shows nothing, just an empty form .
Don't know if it will be useful to mention I input the code on the postForm() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not doing too much in the post method but assuming that you "must" for some reason just make sure you don't [violate the EDT](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html) by calling code on a `readResponse` method or something like that (turn on the EDT violation detection tool in the simulator).

Assuming this is all good I'm guessing you are just missing a call to `revalidate()` after adding everything. When a `Form` is showing you need to call `revalidate()` or one of the `animateLayout()` methods to update it as explained in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html).

Comment: I tried all you said, it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: Did you run in the debugger? Is your code executed? You should see the add calls adding multibuttons to the container followed by a revalidate().

Comment: It works now....using the genericlistrenderer()..but I have another problem, I added an action listener to it and in running, it doesn't work....its supposed to open a form a display labels containing strings from the multbutton pressed....

Comment: I would recommend avoiding lists. They are hard to work with. The events are handled by the list not by the generic list cell render entries

Comment: What do u recommend then?

Comment: We discuss this in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_infinitecontainer_infinitescrolladapter_vs_list_containerlist